# Get-AzureStorageBlobContent Timeout

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-blob-storage

I use PowerShell to download a blob file which is around 10GB.
The command is like this

```html
$StorageContext | Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -blob $bacpacFilename | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Destination $TempWeekLocalPath -ClientTimeoutPerRequest $ClientTimeoutPerRequest -ServerTimeoutPerRequest $ClientTimeoutPerRequest -Force
```

The timeout is set to 18000s which is nearly 5 hours.
However, I got the following error:
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent : The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout. HTTP Status Code:
408 - HTTP Error Message: Partial Content

Comment: Was the answer helpful to your situation ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying AZcopy, the 408 could be a result of connect issue that was dropped in the middle.

AZcopy would be more reliable :

*AzCopy by default copies data between two storage endpoints asynchronously. Therefore, the copy operation runs in the background using spare bandwidth capacity that has no SLA in terms of how fast a blob is copied, and AzCopy periodically checks the copy status until the copying is completed or failed.
The **/SyncCopy** option ensures that the copy operation gets consistent speed. AzCopy performs the synchronous copy by downloading the blobs to copy from the specified source to local memory, and then uploading them to the Blob storage destination.*

**Command Sample:**

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/ /Dest:https://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/ /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /Pattern:ab /SyncCopy
```

More details can be found [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy).